# Does cleaning data before saving fall under the term "data sanitization"?

Tags: terminology, data

I understand that "data sanitization" mainly deals with cleaning user-entered data to prevent harmful effects (e.g. SQL injection), but what about other forms of cleaning data? E.g., trimming whitespace from text or removing leading zeros from numbers. Do these also fall under "data sanitization"? If not, what is this type of data cleaning called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Canonicalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization)

> In computer science, canonicalization (sometimes standardization or normalization) is a process for converting data that has more than one possible representation into a "standard", "normal", or canonical form. This can be done to compare different representations for equivalence, to count the number of distinct data structures, to improve the efficiency of various algorithms by eliminating repeated calculations, or to make it possible to impose a meaningful sorting order.

Comment: `Normalization` is a word my colleagues will probably know as well. Perfect! :)

Comment: Normalisation is the norm here too.